# how to know if socket.Io is connected on android

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to find out whether a Android IO Socket is currently connected, the following (socket.connected) just seems to tell me whether the socket has been connected at some point - not whether it is currently still connected.

Comment: Post code so can suggest from your code otherwise you have to rewrite code if anyone provide code http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html.

Comment: There is no TCP API at any level right down to the metal that can tell you that. All you have is absence of send or receive errors.

Comment: i have created the socket with   try {
            socket=IO.socket("http://192...:8080");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket.connect();

now i want to know if the socket is currently connected. (i used if(socket.connected)) but it tell me whether the socket has been connected at some point

Answer (score 0):

EJP's answer is already good, you basically don't have to check whether the socket is connected or not. The operations on a socket without being connected will result in an exception. Therefore all you have to do is put a try catch around your code. Checking whether the socket is open right before your operations is not enough, because you could get into trouble if this happens:

```
if(socket.isConnected()) {
    // cut the ethernet cable here
    socket.read/write operations
}
```

Also TCP does not handle disconnect events directly. How should one immediately detect disconnects on physical level, if the ethernet cable was cut, or similar? You simply can't, there is always a time necessary for detecting this. For regular disconnects there might be a possibility, but this is not safe either, because of the example I've shown, so you would never be able to trust such a function or method.